# How the passing parameters are assigned to parameters of the function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm unable to understand how '5' or 'A' is assigned to function parameter `i` in return function statement.

```
function negate (f) {
    return function (i) {
        return !f(i);
    };
}
var isNumber = negate(isNaN);
// function object alert(isNumber(5));
// => true alert(isNumber(NaN));
// => false alert(isNumber("A"));
// => false
```

Answer (score 1):

When invoking `negate(isNaN)` function, `isNumber` gets the function as return value:

```js
var isNumber = function (i) {
  return !isNaN(i)
};
```

After that, when calling `isNumber` like `isNumber(5)` or `isNumber('A')`, those are assigned to the parameter `i`.